# Implement redis leaderboard

Tags: database, redis

I have sorted set that use for me as a leaderboard.

I would like to retrieve only N elements from the leaderboard.

For example, My sorted set contains 1 million records.
My userId (value in the sorted set) is 123 with score 100

I would like to get only 10 users above my user and 10 users below my user.

Currently, my logic look like that:

1. I call ZRANK to get my user rank.
2. I call to ZRANGE [key] [USERRANK - 10] [USERRANK + 10]

Now, I have the scores and users that I would like to retrieve from Redis but I don't have the ranks for those users.

Is there a way to get also the ranks?

I don't want to call ZRANK for every user.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a Redis-way to do that, but since you already know the rank of the user, you can use as it as your "basis" from which you decrement/increment according to the position of members on `ZRANGE`'s reply. As it is a bound range of up to 21 members, this is an easy computation that can be done in the client at constant complexity.